# How to insert an array into another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP Array:

```
$mod = array( 1 => array(), 2 => array(), 3 => array());
```

When I `json_encode` `$mod`, it produces this:

```
{"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]}
```

But I want to be able to do this in the following manner:

```
$tstarray = array();
$newaray = array(1 => array());
$newaray2 = array(2 => array());
$newaray3 = array(3 => array());
array_push($tstarray, $newaray);
array_push($tstarray, $newaray2);
array_push($tstarray, $newaray3);
```

When I `json_encode` `$tstarray`, it produces a result like this:

```
[{"1":[]},{"2":[]},{"3":[]}]
```

I want the second result to look like the first result. By "look" I mean the same type. Do you know what I would need to change in order to get this to be the same?

**Update: What end result do I need?**

If I have var `x = 9` Then I need a while loop that will create the `$mod` variable but do it all the way from `1 => array()` to `9 => array()`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array(1 => array());
$arr2 = array(2 => array());
$arr3 = array(3 => array());
$arr = $arr1 + $arr2 + $arr3;

print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

Output is:

```
{"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]}
```

This also works with nested arrays.

```
$arr1 = array(1 => array(1 => "A", 2 => "B"));
$arr2 = array(2 => array(1, 2, 3));
$arr3 = array(3 => array(1 => "C", 2 => "D"));
$arr = $arr1 + $arr2 + $arr3;
print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

Output:

```
{"1":{"1":"A","2":"B"},"2":[1,2,3],"3":{"1":"C","2":"D"}}
```

The problems appear once you start defining zero-indexed values in your arrays... at that point they will start getting json-encoded as true arrays.

**REQUEST UPDATE**

```
$arr = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; ++$i)
    $arr = $arr + array($i => array());

print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

Output:

```
{"1":[],"2":[],"3":[],"4":[],"5":[],"6":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":[]}
```

Comment: Will it also function as an array within an array?

Comment: Anyway yes, it works... but as long as you don't zero-index your arrays, otherwise they will be json-encoded as true arrays.

Comment: Make some tests as I did, for the moment I obtained a 100% behavior match.

Comment: I am new to PHP, so instead of print_r if I use echo, will it be the same?

Comment: Absolutely: echo(json_encode($arr)) prints the same... but never base your assumption on what you print... but on the content.